# error 500 while creating an instance of blazemeter service

Tags: ibm-cloud, blazemeter

I want to do a load performance test of one of my application and trying to explore blazemeter service for the same, however while creating an instance of service, I got the following error.

Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 500 received from broker url https://bluemix.marketplace.ibmcloud.com/api/custom/cloudfoundry/v2/service_instances/f9ab4891-835f-402a-9a56-98dc1f8a553a"}

My understanding of this error is that either the service is down or there is an issue between the network connection of service provider and Bluemix. This is just my guess. If you know how I can resolve this issue, let me know ?

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused when Bluemix isn't able to contact the "create service" endpoint on the broker api. It's likely that something is either temporarily down on Blazemeters end and will hopefully be fixed shortly. In the meantime it seems you can still use blazemeter directly from [their website](http://blazemeter.com)

Comment: thanks for the response. not only blazemeter, i see the same error while trying to create load impact service too. seems like some issue with Bluemix/devops related services. Anyway hoping their is no issue with my account and to see it fixed soon.

Comment: This page on Bluemix.net gives you status on all services and runtimes, as well as updates on any services that are temporarily down for maintenance.